# What type has kdb's xbar time

Tags: python, numpy, kdb, qpython

I'm working on a function (in python, using qPython) that gets history data from a hdb table inside of kdb. I'd like to give the end user as much freedom in this function when it comes to parameters. The query the function builds looks something like this:

`select by 10 xbar time.minute from trade where date within('2017-06-31';'2017-07-01'),sym = 'instr1'`

Here it is again but this time with the variable placeholders:

`'{[a:b;x;y;z]select by a xbar b from trade where date within(x;y),sym in z}',`

My question is about the `time.something` that goes in place of `b`. Whenever I pass a `string`, `numpy.string_`, `byte` or `numpy.bytes_` it throws a `'type exception`.

What type is this `time.*` argument in kdb, and what numpy/qPython type should I use to pass it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use . notation in functions for selects like this e.g.

```
q){select count i by time.minute from x}([]time:2#.z.p)
minute| x
------| -
19:43 | 2
```

Your problem here with the type error is the function declaration:

```
{[a:b;x;y;z]select by a xbar b from trade where date within(x;y),sym in z}
```

The declaration should be

```
{[a;b;x;y;z]select by a xbar b from trade where date within(x;y),sym in z}
```

i.e. you have a : instead of ;

The problem with the casts that you are trying to do is that the data will come back with different types, depending on how you cast it.  You also can't pass in "b" to the function in the way you are trying to.  Personally I would just stick with timestamps (assuming time is a timestamp type) and use the resolution of the parameter to dictate it e.g.

```
q){[b;t] select count i by b xbar time from t}[0D01;([]time:0D 0D00:01 0D01+.z.p)]                                                                                                

time                         | x
-----------------------------| -
2017.08.01D19:00:00.000000000| 2
2017.08.01D20:00:00.000000000| 1
q){[b;t] select count i by b xbar time from t}[0D00:01;([]time:0D 0D00:01 0D01+.z.p)]                                                                                             
time                         | x
-----------------------------| -
2017.08.01D19:48:00.000000000| 1
2017.08.01D19:49:00.000000000| 1
2017.08.01D20:48:00.000000000| 1
q){[b;t] select count i by b xbar time from t}[0D00:00:01;([]time:0D 0D00:01 0D01+.z.p)]                                                                                          
time                         | x
-----------------------------| -
2017.08.01D19:48:30.000000000| 1
2017.08.01D19:49:30.000000000| 1
2017.08.01D20:48:30.000000000| 1
```

As for the python type, not sure but I think it's numpy.datetime64

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your response. Your answer makes me realise how little I know about how kdb actually works. Since I did not create the database I'm working with and the docs for xbar at http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/xbar refer to time.minute, I assumed time.minute was some global keyword like mysql's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for instance. You saying "assuming time is a timestamp type" made me realise it's simply being sorted by a column.. I feel pretty stupid but I'll survive ;) Thanks for your elaborate answer, it's deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any temporal types with dot notation;

For example time.dd, time.hh, time.mm, time.month, time.year.

This is not supported in functions however so you should use the cast notation instead;

```
select by 10 xbar `minute$time from trade where date within('2017-06-31';'2017-07-01'),sym = 'instr1'
```

http://code.kx.com/q4m3/2_Basic_Data_Types_Atoms/#257-constituents-and-dot-notation

Comment: The first query I wrote actually worked. It was when adding the variable placeholders (`a;b;x;y;z`) in the second example where my problems arose. Thanks for your thoughts though! It is appreciated :-)